# Automatische grammatikalische Satzanalyse

Tags: software

Ich suche ein Programm oder einen Web-Dienst, bei dem man einen deutschen Satz eingibt, und wo dann ausgegeben wird, was davon ein Nebensatz, ein Prädikat oder ein Genitivattribut usw. ist.

Ich habe sowas schon mal gesehen, ich glaube als online-Dienst im Internet, finde aber die Adresse dieses Dienstes nicht mehr.

Kann mir bitte jemand die Adresse dieses Dienstes nennen?

Answer (score 3):

Der [Stanford-Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) kann auch Deutsch. Es gibt ihn auch als [Web-Dienst](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/), allerdings kann dieser nur Arabisch, Chinesisch, Englisch und Spanisch.

Hier ein Minimalbeispiel, wie man die Java-Version offline benutzt (man braucht Java mindestens in der Version 1.7):

- Stanford-Parser Version 3.4.1 [herunterladen](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-parser-full-2014-08-27.zip) und entpacken (eine ZIP-Datei).
- In dem entstandenen Ordner die Datei `stanford-parser-3.4.1-models.jar` ebenfalls entpacken (wie jede JAR-Datei ist dies auch einfach eine ZIP-Datei).
- Das Java-Programm `stanford-parser.jar` ausführen (z.B. Kommandozeile unter Linux oder Mac: in das Verzeichnis wechseln, dann `java -jar stanford-parser.jar`
- In der GUI erst auf "Load File" klicken und dann die Adresse einer Web-Seite eingeben, oder eine lokale Datei mit "Browse" öffnen. Im Verzeichnis `data` liegt ein Minimalbeispiel `german-onesent.txt`.
- Mit "Load Parser" die Datei `edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/germanPCFG.ser.gz` laden.
- Auf "Parse" klicken. Es sollte ein Syntaxbaum angezeigt werden.

Answer (score 2):

Ich habe jetzt selbst den gesuchten Webdienst gefunden. (Danke, JTextor für das Stichwort »Parser«! damit habe ich dann auch bei Google etwas gefunden)

https://pub.cl.uzh.ch/demo/parzu/

Auf dieser Seite gibt es noch mehr Links:
http://bubenhofer.com/sprechtakel/2011/09/12/baume-zeichnen-maschinelles-syntaktisches-parsing-deutsch/